# HTML5 record moderate video quality for upload to be playable by Safari

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc

I am creating a web-based mobile app where it should be possible to upload video-recordings.
There are two ways to achieve this:

**Use input:**

```
<input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*" capture></input>
```

**Use RTC MediaRecorder:**

```
var recordedBlobs = [];
function handleDataAvailable(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
    }
}

var options = {
    mimeType: 'video/webm',
    audioBitsPerSecond : 128000,
    videoBitsPerSecond : 2500000
}

mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
mediaRecorder.start(10);
```

While the first option always works the main problem is that it uses the build-in mobile camera application leaving us no control over quality, which again leads to potentially very large files (especially on android)

Second version gives us full control over quality and lets os create moderate file sizes that are size-wise acceptable as content in the application. iOS/Safari does not support this feature yet, but this is ok since iPhones record small files by default when started from the browser. So I can activate option 1 when the user-agent is iOS.

Now the problems:

First option would be fine if I could:

1. Control the video recording quality of the mobile application
2. Post-elaborate the recording to change the resolution before upload

The problem with option 2 is that only the .webm container type is supported, and Safari does not support this type.

So I'm a little stuck - right now it seems like my only option is to post-convert the incoming .webm files to .mp4 on the server as they are uploaded. But it seems to be a very CPU costly process on the server.

Any good ideas?

Comment: If you want post-processing, you would have to either store the `.webm` file on the client or on a server, and convert it to `.mp4` file. On server side, you can do it with FFMpeg. On the client side, you can use open source libraries to convert it.

Comment: I can say that I have been down the road of converting webm to mp4 with ffmpeg on the server side. I even made a nice script that can show progress as percentage. But conversion is both time and CPU consuming. I wanted to do a ffmpeg -c copy and thereby omitting re-encoding. But unfortunately this is not possible with the webm container. If I could run a ffmpeg command that could just convert without re-encoding, then that would be the solution.

Comment: *"If I could run a ffmpeg command that could just convert without re-encoding"* - Not possible. You cannot convert one format to another without re-encoding it, .webm and .mp4 are profoundly different.

Comment: Why can't Safari just handle webm like all other browses ... Not a real question, just my frustration.

Comment: Because Apple HAVE to be special. They wake up each morning thinking "how can we destroy dome developers today?"

Answer (score 4):

You can record as H.264 into a webm container. This is supported by Chrome.

```
var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'};

media_recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

Although it is an usual combination of video format and container - it is valid.

Now you could change H.264/webm into H.264/mp4 without transcoding the video stream using ffmepg  (-vcodec copy).

You could also try re-wrapping from webm to mp4 client side in JavaScript using ffmpeg.js.

Comment: I just tried with the -vcodec copy on a video/webm;codecs=h264 recorded feed. I ran this command:

`ffmpeg test.webm -vcodec copy test.mp4`

got the following error: Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Comment: If I could do the non-transcoding format change, then it is for sure the solution I need.

Comment: Man I forgot `-i` :-D

Comment: Damn it worked on a Chrome desktop browser but not an Android mobile phone :-( It seems to totally ignore the codecs=h264 and just use VP8.

Comment: What version of Android? Enabling H.264 in MediaRecorder is relative recently.

Comment: It's Android 7.0